# TFS: How can I create a project group before creating the project?

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

One of my colleagues quit last year and I am now responsible for some of his old tasks. He created a customized process template for us. I downloaded it now from TFS and am trying to upload it again into a new collection.

This does not work, because some of the work item type definitions uses a group called "[Project]\Project Managers". The following error appears:

> VS402504: User or group cannot be found: [Project]\Project Managers.
>   Verify that the users and groups used in your work item type
>   definition exist.

I added the group "Project Managers" to TFS but still the same error appears. But how can I create such a group without creating a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an validation error, custom project scoped groups are not supported. You can only reference account level scoped groups.

So you need to create a new **account (collection) level group** "`Project Managers`" and reference it accordingly in the specific work item type definition file (`XML`).

Please refer to [VS402504: User or group cannot be found [project]\Group Name. Verify that the users and groups used in your work item type definition exist.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/import-process/resolve-errors?view=vsts#vs402504-user-or-group-cannot-be-found-projectgroup-name-verify-that-the-users-and-groups-used-in-your-work-item-type-definition-exist) for details.

> **Error example**
>
> Bug.xml is referencing a project scoped group.
>
> ```
> ... "[project]\Project Managers"
> ```
>
> **Resolution example**
>
> Create a new account (collection) level group "Organization Leaders"
>   and reference it accordingly in the XML.
>
> ```
> ... "[global]\Project Managers"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new groups in the process template by editing the file `GroupsAndPermissions.xml` (exist in the folder "Groups And Permissions"):

```
<group name="New Group" description="Test Desc">
  <permissions>
   ... add here the permissions
  </permissions>
</group>
```

When you add there the new groups you can use them in the `workitems.xml` in the regular way:

```
"[project]\New Group"
```